# Xml request header with root element in swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift, soap, alamofire

I've been trying to make xml request using `Alamofire`. However, I got `<soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---> Root element is missing.</soap:Text>` error. Actually, this is my first experience about xml request in ios. How can I achieve to make this request without issue. Here is my code;

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://example.com/WS.asmx?op=AuthenticateUser", parameters: nil, encoding: .PropertyList(.XMLFormat_v1_0, 0), headers: ["Username": "username", "Password": "password" , "AuthenticatedToken" : "123123"])
                    .responsePropertyList { response in 
    let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
                        print(xml) 
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Could you help me please ?

Thank you for your answers

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://example.com/WS.asmx?op=AuthenticateUser", 
    parameters: nil, 
    // Try ->
    encoding: .Custom({
       (convertible, params) in
           let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
           mutableRequest.HTTPBody =       
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
                <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions\"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
                  <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---> Root element is missing.</soap:Text>
                 </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

        return (mutableRequest, nil)}),
     headers: 
        ["Username": "username",
         "Password": "password" ,
         "AuthenticatedToken" : "123123"])
     .responsePropertyList { response in 
           let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
                    print(xml)
```

}